# Browsing for file location and saving wstring to file

Tags: c++, string, file

I am trying to create a file dialog where the user selects an existing file or create a new one by selecting a location and entering a name. The browsing works fine, but when I try to save the file, it gives me the following error

> fail: file != NULL.

I also have to convert the text that is meant to be written to the file from `std::wstring` to `char *`, hence the sprint. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Below is the code I am currently working with:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HWND hwnd = NULL;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrTitle = TEXT("Select a location to save the information");
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0");
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if(GetSaveFileName(&ofn)==TRUE)
{
    wchar_t hostName[2048] = L"";
    DWORD sz = 2048;

    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ,
      0, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
      OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      (HANDLE)NULL);

    char * buffer = new char[242];
    //sprintf(buffer, "%ls", hostInfo.c_str());
    _snprintf_s(buffer,242, _TRUNCATE, "%ls", hostInfo.c_str());

    std::ofstream stream(ofn.lpstrFile, std::ofstream::binary);
    stream.write(buffer, 243);

    //delete[] buffer;
    stream.close();
}
```

EDIT:
Found the problem. I did not set the pointer for `lpstrFile` resulting in the selected path being `NULL` hence the `File != NULL` assert fail

Comment: Why CreateFile() with GENERIC_READ and then (keeping it open) you create ofstream for writing?

Comment: I tried multiple things. I thought i had to create the file before writing to it..

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. It might be that you cannot write to the file because it is still open, as Adriano recognized. Try removing CreateFile entirely